# Django Wagtail ajax contact form

Tags: html, ajax, django, wagtail

I have a contact form that appears at the bottom of every page in the footer. I simply included it in my base.html at the bottom. Now i want to figure out a way to submit it. All the examples wagtail provides is under the assumption i have an entire page dedicated to it and hence submits to itself.

This cannot work for me as its not a page.

I have written pseudo code of what I think it should look like .

```
def submitContact(request): 
        source_email = request.POST.get('email')
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        message = request.POST.get('message')           
        if (source_email is not None) and (name is not None) and (message is not None):
            body = "sample"
            send_mail(
                name,
                message,
                source_email,
                ['test@foobar'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

Then my form would be something like this

```
<form class="form-group" role="form" method="post" action="/submitContact">
 ......
</form>
```

Ideally if someone could point to Wagtail resources that show how to create endpoints in models that do not inherit from the Page model and are not snippets that maintain "request" content that would be useful. Ideally what I would prefer is to log this data into contact "table" then send the email after.

What should I add to my urls.py to reroute the request with the correct context for the function to retrieve the required variables and thus send the email

**Additional info**

I wrapped a snippet around the footer to provide some context to it using templatetags, just putting this out there incase it adds value

See below.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('home/menus/footer.html', takes_context=True)
def footers(context):
    return {
        'footers': Footers.objects.first(),
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

Comment: If you're not inheriting from the Page model, then there's really nothing Wagtail-specific about what you're trying to do, and so the Wagtail documentation won't cover this - you're just writing a plain Django view. If you're not familiar with writing Django views, start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Is there a better way to do it with Wagtail itself?

Comment: No, probably not. Wagtail is designed to work alongside Django's feature set, not to be a layer on top of it. There are plenty of things Django is very good at, and processing form submissions and putting them into a database is one of them... in those cases, working directly with Django is absolutely the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag.

*urls.py* :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from yourapp.views import submitContact

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/$', submitContact, name='contact'),
]
```

*Template* :

```
<form class="form-group" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'contact' %}">
 ......
</form>
```

Another improvement is to use Django Form.

Note : prefer *lower_case_with_underscores* naming style for functions. Use *CamelCase* for classes. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to build it yourself, why not take a look at the already existing Form Builder of Wagtail?

It enables you to create a FormPage on which you can display a custom form and even E-mail the results.

[Check out the documentation here](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/forms/index.html).

Comment: OP clearly stated that he doesn't want an entire page dedicated for a single form.

Comment: Doesn't have to be, it's just a form so posting your data to it via AJAX or something can be easily achieved. Never bad to look at alternatives using tools that are already in your toolkit or even use parts of them.

Comment: If it's possible, your answer clearly lack details. The documentation mention nothing about Ajax, and for beginner like me, I can't make anything work with your answer as is.